# Person with different sizes, dimensions or what?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, phrase-requests

What expression is better to say persons with different sizes ? Persons who have different shapes.

Context: I am doing an info-graphics simulation of a real scene. I am using 3 persons with different shapes. So, I need to comments this in a report.

I need to say: In this simulation, we used 3 persons with different _____

Comment: Can you provide some context for this question and include an example sentence where you'd use this?  People come in *all shapes and sizes*

Comment: @Jim, I updated my question

Comment: I would say *…we used 3 persons with different **body measurements***. Or ***body types***.

Comment: What kind of differences are you referring to? There are literally thousands of things that can be differently shaped. Height, width, general body types, shape of the face, ... <extend to infinity>

Comment: @Helmar, height, width and weight

Comment: Please use "people" not "persons".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you're trying to say. Are these stick figures with different stick bodies? Are they cartoon characters with literal shapes for bodies? Are they real people?

If they're real people, you could say: we used 3 people with different **weights** and **heights**.

More generally, you could say you used people with different [**body shapes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_shape):

> Human body shape is a complex phenomenon with sophisticated detail and function. The general shape or figure of a person is defined mainly by the molding of skeletal structures, as well as the distribution of muscles and fat.

Answer (score 1):

### Morphology

**[1. b:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morphology)** "the form and structure of an organism or any of its parts"

> In this simulation, we used 3 persons with different morphologies, Ectomorph, Mesomorph and Endomorph respectively.